# Javascript Condition : Real time validation

Tags: javascript

Can anyone please help me fix my javascript condition.

The scenario is this.

When I input 9 digit, label should turn red. But if the field is empty and i input 10 digit, label should turn blue. Im having a hard time to fix this.

```js
function validateField(testField)
{
  var reg2 = /^([\d])/;

  if(testField.value.length > 0)
  {
    if(reg2.test(testField) == false)
    {
      document.getElementById("testlabel").style.color="red"
      return false;
    }
    else
    {
      document.getElementById("testlabel").style.color="black"
      return true;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    document.getElementById("testlabel").style.color="blue";
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<label id="testlabel">Test101: </label>
<input name="txtNum" type="text" id="Num" pattern=".{10,}" minlength="10" maxlength="10" onblur="validateField(this);" >
```

Comment: Doesn't the above code error? `if(reg2.test(testField) == false)` testfield is the input element here, not the value of it. Try `testField.value` to get the number inside. Then you can add an if/else for the length of the input.

Comment: Can you clarify what you actually want to be in your field? Numbers or text?

Comment: @evolutionxbox , the value to be input should be number but we want the input type as text.

Comment: reg2.test(testField) need to become reg2.test(testField.value)

Comment: This `pattern=".{10,}"` suggests you want any input, this `/^([\d])/` will only match a single digit, and `reg2.test(testField)` won't do anything.

Comment: @Vanojx1 it should be the answer. http://jsbin.com/colurip/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code

1. **Regex** - If you need to validate the Regex for having 10 digits only then you can use the Regex `\d{10}`. Your Regex `^([\d])` only matches a digit at the start of the string.
2. `reg2.test(testField)` should be changed to `reg2.test(testField.value)`, you are trying to compare the TextBox value and not the textbox itself.

```js
function validateField(testField)
{
 var reg2 = /\d{10}/;
 
 if(testField.value.length > 0)
 {
  if(reg2.test(testField.value) == false)
  {
   document.getElementById("testlabel").style.color="red"
   return false;
  }
  else
  {
   document.getElementById("testlabel").style.color="blue"
   return true;
  }
 }
 else
 {
  document.getElementById("testlabel").style.color="black";
  return true;
 }
}
```

```html
<label id="testlabel">Test101: </label>
<input name="txtNum" type="text" id="Num" pattern=".{10,}" minlength="10" maxlength="10" onblur="validateField(this);" >
```

Comment: this is it! exactly! this is exactly what i need to do. thanks for your very well said explanation Sir!